# Running Internet Explorer on LocalSystem Account on Windows 2012

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, service, selenium-grid

I'm setting up Selenium Grid. We have a separate machine for each version of the browser.

Each node is started as System Service running on LocalSystem account with interactions with user desktop enabled.

This is required because Selenium Grid node starting Internet Explorer have problems making screenshots and transferring them when there was no interaction with user desktop.

As far as I was able to check, it looks like that interactions with user desktop for service are only allowed for LocalSystem account. Event changing manually flags in registry does not seem to works (as it was in windows 2008)

Everything is working fine except the test where I need to perform upload of the file. When there is an action to open dialog for file browsing, following popup appears

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this (creation of folder Desktop does not seem to work) ?

From the other hand, if there is a way to run service under different account with interactions with user desktop enabled, that would also be a case.

I would appreciate any help because I'm stuck with the problem

Comment: I had previously thought that (since Windows Vista) all accounts have been locked from having "interactions with desktop" despite the fact that the checkbox is still there.   So, this is news to me that "LocalSystem" account worked for you.  If you have "Windows Server" edition, what I usually do is run the Grid in the foreground of a permanently open session.  Of course, this doesn't allow you to have the service capability of starting when the system starts (unless you also login to the account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked some additional solutions, like running selenium grid nodes via PowerShell Invoke-Command and this did not worked too.

I have managed to run selenium grid nodes as Windows Service with desktop interactions using 3rd party tool FireDaemon Pro Service Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this but `PsExec -s` should work
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553